# Проблема с получением сохраненного файла

Tags: java, android

Создаю файл:

```
try {
        // отрываем поток для записи
        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput(FILENAME, MODE_PRIVATE));
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(writer);
        // пишем данные
        bw.write("Содержимое файла");
        // закрываем поток
        bw.close();
     } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

Затем мне необходимо отправить его по почте для этого получаю файл и проверяю на наличие

```
    File file = new File(FILENAME);
    if(file.exists()) {
        ...
    }
```

Но почему то он не видит его (не проходит условие if), хотя когда я его загружаю через поток все прекрасно грузится.

```
try {
        // открываем поток для чтения
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                openFileInput(FILENAME)));
        String str = "";
        // читаем содержимое
        while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, str);

        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Я предполагаю что проблема где-то в File(FILENAME). Подскажите новичку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело в том, что вызов `new File(FILENAME)` предполагает, что `FILENAME` находится в каталоге `System.getProperty("user.dir")`, а `openFileOutput()` в каталоге `context.getFilesDir()`

Поэтому вы видите то что видите.

Надо проверять наличие файла через

```
File file=new File(context.getFilesDir(), FILENAME);
if(file.exists()) {
     //blah-blah
}
```